# Use Str_to_map in bigquery

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, hive, maps, key-value

I have a function str_to_map() in hive that I need to convert to Big Query. As we don't have map in Bigquery, I want to find another way to have a map format and then after that to extract the key-values by using the key name.

```
Example :
Select str_to_map('cars:0,kids:143,cats:1,lost:0,win:1,chances:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,missed:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0',',',':')
```

If I call the key 'cars' I get the value '0'.
If I call the key 'chances' I should get '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0'

It's necessary for me to have a type like the 'map' type (key-value).

Thank you

Comment: Except **0:0:0:0:0:0** part, you can visit https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/blob/master/udfs/community/cw_map_parse.sqlx and get some idea of it. . this place is kind of **brickhouse** in Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides some useful UDFs for BigQuery here in [bigquery-utils](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#community-udfs).

> Don't reinvent the wheel

So, I brought two udfs to answer this question.

##### 1. [get_value(k STRING, arr ANY TYPE)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#get_valuek-string-arr-any-type)

> Given a key and a list of key-value maps in the form [{'key': 'a', 'value': 'aaa'}], returns the SCALAR type value.

##### 2. [cw_map_parse(m string, pd string, kvd string)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#cw_map_parsem-string-pd-string-kvd-string)

> String to map convert.

With these, you can write a query like below:

```sql
SELECT get_value('kids', cw_map_parse(str, ',', ':')) kids,
       get_value('chances', cw_map_parse(str, ',', ':')) chances,
  FROM UNNEST(['cars:0,kids:143,cats:1,lost:0,win:1,chances:0,missed:0']) str;
+------+---------+
| kids | chances |
+------+---------+
|  143 |       0 |
+------+---------+
```

But due to below requirements, **cw_map_parse** implementation needs to be customized a little bit.

> If I call the key 'cars' I get the value '0'. If I call the key 'chances' I should get '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0'

Below is a query with cutomized UDFs functions. `str_to_map()` is a customized version of `cw_map_parse()`.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION str_to_map(m string, pd string, kvd string)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>> AS (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT kv[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS key, kv[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS value
      FROM (
        SELECT SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(kv, r'^(.*?)' || kvd, r'\1|'), '|') AS kv 
          FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(m, pd)) AS kv
      )
));

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_value(get_key STRING, arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(arr) WHERE key = get_key)
);

SELECT get_value('cars', map) cars,
       get_value('kids', map) kids,
       get_value('chances', map) chances,
       get_value('missed', map) missed,
  FROM UNNEST(['cars:0,kids:143,cats:1,lost:0,win:1,chances:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,missed:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0']) str,
       UNNEST([STRUCT(str_to_map(str, ',', ':') AS map)]);

+------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| cars | kids |               chances               |               missed                |
+------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|    0 |  143 | 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 | 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 |
+------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another super simple option for that particular case

```
select 
  json_value(json, '$.cars') cars,
  json_value(json, '$.kids') kids,
  json_value(json, '$.cats') cats,
  json_value(json, '$.lost') lost,
  json_value(json, '$.win') win,
  json_value(json, '$.chances') chances,
  json_value(json, '$.missed') missed
from your_table, 
unnest([format('{%s}', regexp_replace(str, r'([^:,]+):([\d:]*\d)', r'"\1":"\2"'))]) json
```

with output

[image]